# Current path on page in functions.php

Tags: functions, paths, cookies

How can I get the current path of my page?

I know how to do it inside a template file, but I need it inside `functions.php`.
And it has to be before the `send_headers` hook, because I'll use this info to set a cookie.

I tried using PHP, but I'm getting `/wp-admin`

Comment: Do you mean `parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] )`?

Comment: Do you want to get path or URl of page?

Answer (score 1):

```
//get current page's path
$pagePath = parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
$pagePath = $pagePath['path'];
$pagePath = substr($pagePath, 1, -1);//remove slashes
```

Comment: Rather use [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove slashes.

Comment: Or there's a WordPress function [untrailingslashit](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/untrailingslashit/). (Which uses rtrim.)